# Минимальная высота строки/ячейки в DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, height

Есть таблица `DataGridView` с содержимым ячеек разного размера. Хотелось установить минимальную высоту чтобы выровнять все строки по высоте и убрать пустое место между границей элемента и последней строкой при прокрутки до конца. Возможно подобное для данного элемента в WinForms?

[image: Превью]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу предлагаю такой вариант, выровняются все по самой широкой строке.
Я думаю вы это имели ввиду, ибо "Хотелось установить минимальную высоту" не совсем понятно как, в отдельном текстбоксе?

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            int max = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                if (max < row.Height)
                    max = row.Height;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                row.Height = max;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
        }
```

Вот так это у меня выглядит

[image: Как выглядит]

Comment: Ваш код не работает. Минимальное значение высоты означает, что элемент не будет схлопываться по высоте меньше указанного значения. Т.е. я могу выставить минимальное значение, которое будет достаточно чтобы ячейка не расширялась и не уменьшалась в пределах моего контента.

Comment: @Rootware По подробнее, что значит не работает? Или всё -же работает, но не как вам надо? 
Я правда, по вашим комментариям не понимаю как именно вам надо, вы хотите где-то в текстбоксе высоту написать вашу минимальную, или чтобы когда к краю ячейки курсор подводишь была возможность изменить, но так, чтобы если  делаешь меньше чем можно(чтобы все символы ячейки видны были)  не давало уменьшить, так?

Comment: Я картинку приложил. Посмотрите насколько ровные по высоте строки сейчас. даже если я добавляю ваш код и регистрирую событие, то ничего существенного не меняется во внешнем виде. Я их хочу выровнять и сделать одной высоты. Т.е. минимальное значение высоты приравнять к реальному максимальному.

Comment: @Rootware Посмотрите, дополнил картинкой. Так вам надо? Этот код работает при ручном редактировании, возможно при бинде данных ч/з Visual Forms данные загружаются без вызова этого события, вы же не указали как заполняете таблицу, попробуйте добавить всё это после  InitializeComponent();

Comment: Возможно. У меня используется виртуальный режим. Данные записываются через объект. Это уменьшает проблемы с отрисовкой элемента при переключении вкладок. Я проверю чуть позже ваш код в другом событии. По результатам отпишусь.

Comment: Добавил ваш код в событие Form_Loaded() и заработало. Видимо в виртуальном режиме не работает событие CellChanged(). Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView_RowHeightChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    e.Row.MinimumHeight = 40;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]